# Text File processing - using java

Tags: java, text, lookup

Need a help. I have a big text file which has location data (represented numerically) and needs to be replaced with its corresponding location. These two files are separate text files.

Could you help with the java utility on how to replace the numeric values in one file using location values for the other.

Below is an example of the contents of file 1 and file 2. File 1 has numeric data and text. The numeric data in the first column needs to be replaced with the corresponding entry from file2. Thus, the file 1 needs to be looped for each entry in file 2.

```
Text File1: 19922973   @Uniquehope was good 
Test File2: 19922973   Chicago, IL
```

Need to replace 19922973 with Chciago, IL.
Please provide your inputs.

Thanks
Saurabh

Comment: You say you "need to replace", but you don't even tell where and for what purpose; what is more, and more importantly, where is the code?

Comment: @fge : I haven't written the code yet. still deciding on how to proceed with it.

Comment: OK well, to be abrupt and sorry for that, SO is not a free coding service; now, less abrupt, learning how to program will mean you'll get burnt before you get it right, so try and do it by your own means; if you cannot, then ask a question. Also, remember not to fall prey to the [XY problem syndrome](http://xyproblem.info)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have two loops. First read in the "big" text file and split each line into a HashMap entry with the number as the key and the remainder as the value, and the second loop would read the File1, split it into an array with two elements, look up the number in your HashMap, and replace the number with the value from the HashMap, and write out the results to a new file.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Answer (score 1):

It's simple! I think the most efficient way to do this would be to read the second file first, and then create a `HashMap` of all the values where the key would be the first column and the values would be the second column.

You can get these two columns by performing a simple `split()` on each of the entries into the 2nd file.

Then, in the first file, do the same splitting, and then perform a replace using the `HashMap` you just created. (Of course for this, you would need to read the 1st file into some buffer, then apply the replacement and write back to the file again. I don't think you can do a string replacement just like that into a file.)